# Need help in Automated userid generation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I want to generate a login id automatically. Logic is to take the user's last name and append a number(like 1, then 2 , then 3). system will also check if this user id exist in database. I have cached the database data in a local variable. If the user id is unique, it will be populated in a text box, otherwise it will append a new number. But This process may go for 10 times, if 10 user has same last name. Could anybody provide a simple solution for this. I want this to be done in JQuery.

Comment: `I have cached the database data in a local variable` - excellent idea, that way anyone with a browser can see your database data - the only possible use for jQuery is a *lazy* way to populate the text box, otherwise the rest of the code would be **javascript**.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok I can use ajax to get the data from database. that is not an issue. i just want to know how can i achieve the requirement in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say John Doe tries to register an account. You need to:

1. Send 'Doe' to backend via ajax
2. Execute a query like this to find the greatest Doe* in DB:

   SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `surname` = 'Doe' ORDER BY `added_ts` DESC LIMIT 1
3. If a record is found, extract the number part out of the user id and send it back, if no record is found simply send `0` back
4. When ajax response arrives, increment the number you get and concatenate it to the surname.

I am assuming you have a record timestamp of some sort to use in the query (`added_ts`).

Edit: @Jaromanda X 8 pointed correctly that the query might return wrong results and it should be the `surname` field we need to check.

Comment: `WHERE user_id LIKE 'Doe%'` too simplistic ... what if you have surnames like `Doer0` ... `Doer8` and then Doe comes along - he would get Doe9 for no reason at all :p ... how about `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE surname='Doe' ORDER BY added_ts DESC LIMIT 1` instead :p

Comment: I wanted a solution written in jquery :(

Comment: @ArpitaDutta This cannot be done without checks done on the server .. Steps 1 and 4 could be jQuery code. Also, note that we are here to help, not to write your code for you.